# How to prevent autorefresh in Kendo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, page-refresh

I want to sort my grid by StartDate automatically. I have added a sort command in my code

```
grid.dataSource.sort({field: "StartTime", dir: "desc"});
```

Sorting works great, but the grid is refreshing continuously, it doesn't stop. How can I prevent it? This command is part of my dataSource.

Comment: I'm afraid this behaviour isn't normal, can't you share your full grid code?

Comment: from the description I can guess that you are calling the sort function in grid dataBound, dataBinding or some other event which is causing grid to refresh continuously. Add complete code...